# Passing javascript object to flex

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, safari, swfobject

I have a very strange issue.
My web application pass a javascript object to flex application using addCallback function.
when the flex application is in modal dialog in safari browser, the object in the flex application is null and when i open the flex application just in a new window, the object is passed correctly.
but, I need the showmodaldialog to show the flex application.
any ideas???

the flex code:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback( "handleEvent", handleEvent );



override public function handleEvent( event:Object ):Object
    {
        Alert.show(String(event)); .....
```

Comment: try ExternalInterface.call(...);

Comment: I'm talking about invoke flex methods through javascript.

Comment: Your explanation isn't very clear. Also, show more code if possible.

Answer (score -1):

Might be a sync problem as Alert.show stops the app, maybe some other javascript call came during the alert.show ?
Need more code :)

Comment: The Alert.show is used to debug my flex app, the issue was there before it.

Comment: -1: `Alert.show()` doesn't stop the Application; if it did the UI would freeze.  Rather it retains **focus** of the Application, and will hold it until the user closes the popup (or another component takes focus programatically).  One can continue to run things in the background.